# Openshift - Internal NGINX proxy can't connect to Openshift route hostname

Tags: nginx, proxy, routes, openshift

My use-case requires pass-through SSL, so we unforunately can't use path-based routing natively in Openshift. Our next best solution was to set up an internal NGINX proxy to route traffic from a path to another web UI's Openshift route. I'm getting errors when doing so.

Here's my simplified NGINX config:

```
    worker_processes auto;                                          
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    pid /etc/nginx/nginx.pid;                                                                                                                                                                    

    include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;                                                                                                                                                                                     
    events {                                            
        worker_connections  1024;                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                       
    http {                                                                   
        upstream app1-ui-1-0 {                         
            server app1-1-0.192.168.99.100.nip.io:443;                                                         
        }                                                               

        server {                                                               
          listen 8443 ssl default_server;                               

          location /apps/app1/ {                                                           
              proxy_pass https://app1-ui-1-0/;                                             
          }                                                                           
        }                                                                      
    }
```

My app1 route configuration is as follows:

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Route
    metadata:
      name: app1-1-0
    spec:
      host: app1-1-0.192.168.99.100.nip.io
      to:
        kind: Service
        name: app1-1-0
      tls:
        insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
        termination: passthrough
```

- When I hit `https://app1-1-0.192.168.99.100.nip.io`, the app works fine.
- When I hit the NGINX proxy route url (`https://proxier-1-0.192.168.99.100.nip.io`), it properly loads up the nginx's standard index.html place.
- However, when I try to hit app1 through the proxy via `https://proxier-1-0.192.168.99.100.nip.io/apps/apps1/`, I get the following Openshift error:

  ```
  Application is not available

  The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.
  ```

Via logs and testing, I know the request is getting into the `/apps/app1/` location block, but it never gets to app1's NGINX. I've also confirmed this error is coming from either app1's router or service, but I don't know how to troubleshoot since neither has logs.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why use the route and not internal dns?

Comment: Yep, you're a genius. I dropped the route and referenced the service directly via internal DNS and it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, posted more detailed explanation in case anyone else hits this

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I don't know that I can use the solution posted below because my Nginx server is located in one Openshfit cluster and the proxy server is located in another. Is there a solution that uses the route with TLS passthrough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to make a request to some other application running in the same OpenShift cluster, the correct solution in most cases is to use the internal DNS.

OpenShift ships with a SDN which enables comms between Pods. This is more efficient than communicating to another Pod via its route since this will typically route the request back onto the public internet before it hits the OpenShift router again and is at that point forwarded via the SDN.

Services can be reached `<service>.<pod_namespace>.svc.cluster.local` which in your case enables NGINX to proxy via `server apps1-1-0.myproject.svc.cluster.local`

Routes should typically be used to route external traffic into the cluster.

See [OpenShift docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/architecture/networking/networking.html) for more details on networking

Comment: I'm having the same issue detailed in the original post, but I don't know that I can use this solution because my Nginx server is located in one Openshfit cluster and the proxy server is located in another. Is there a solution that uses the https route instead?

Answer (score 1):

Per a comment above, I ended up dropping the route and referencing the service's internal DNS in NGINX's upstream:

```
upstream finder-ui-1-0 {                                                                                                                                                                 
    server apps1-1-0.myproject.svc.cluster.local:443;                                                                                                                                
}
```

This suited my needs just fine and worked well.